# What band did walkie-talkies use in Europe before PMR446 was allocated?

Tags: history, europe, ht

The PMR446 band, now used for walkie talkies in Europe, was only allocated after 1997. I'm sure walkie talkies existed before that. What radio bands did those use?

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, we had CB walkie-talkies on the UK FM CB band (the so-called "CB 27/81" specification for 27MHz CB agreed in 1981), which had a bonkers set of frequencies - 40 channels of FM, separated by 10kHz each, from 27.60125MHz to 27.99125MHz. I believe that the main reason that they decided on that exact system was to render imported US AM CB radios useless in the UK. Also, FM produces less interference to electrical equipment than AM does.

As well as CB 27/81 there was CB 934/81, which was another FM UHF CB allocation. Equipment for this band was so expensive that hardly anyone used it. I don't know if there were any walkie talkies available for this band though.

Additionally there were baby monitors, and some walkie-talkies, on the 49MHz band - also FM.

Answer (score 1):

I do vividly remember hearing CB radios talking, in the 80s and central EU.
So it was likely around the "27 MHz" band.